# ASP.NET Core 2 load conventional routes (routing table) from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Core 2 application. I configure my middleware in the `Startup.cs` Configure method. In this Method - Configure - I'm setting my conventional routes as well. (I don't need Attribute routing in my application).

The problem is, as soon as the application is going to grow, the configuration might become a little bit confusing due to the huge amount of code.

Now I try to figure out, how to load the conventional routing table from an external class.

My current routing table looks very regular like that:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Now I try to figure out, how to load my routes from another class:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        // .. I want to load my conventional routes from an external class
    });
}
```

I just figured there is a way to create an extension method using the RouteBuilder class, like in this post:

[How to write a middleware as custom router in asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519352/how-to-write-a-middleware-as-custom-router-in-asp-net-core)

Hence, in my Configure method I could simply call something like that:

```
app.UseMyCoolRouter();
```

My problem is, I don't really know how to configre the RouteHandler to process regular requests:

```
var rh = new RouteHandler(context => 
{
    // ... how to configure for regular routes?
});

var rb = new RouteBuilder(app, rh);

rb.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.UseRouter(rb.Build());
```

When I create the RouteBuilder instance without a RouteHandler:

```
var rb = new RouteBuilder(app);
```

I'm only getting an Null reference exception:

*"A default handler must be set on the IRouteBuilder."*

Do you know how I can load my routing table from another class or extension method into my Configure Method in Startup.cs?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Just pass `routes` to that external class and let it configure them

Comment: It's not quite what I'm looking for, thanks though! I'd like to create an extension method like in this post:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519352/how-to-write-a-middleware-as-custom-router-in-asp-net-core

Comment: and use the extenion method to configure all my conventional routes...

Comment: Still don't see what a problem is, Create extension method then and use it: 'routes.UseMyConventionalRoutes()'.

Comment: yep, I'm trying to. My problem is I look for a way to set up the RouteHandler() for conventional routes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
public class Startup
{
   //...    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {   
        app.UseDemoRoutes();
    }
}

public static class ApplicationExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseDemoRoutes(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc(routes => new DemoRouter(routes));

        return app;
    }
}

public class DemoRouter
{    
    public DemoRouter(IRouteBuilder routes)
    {
        ConfigureRoutes(routes);
        // ConfigureMoreRoutes(routes);
    }

    private void ConfigureRoutes(IRouteBuilder routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    }
}
```

First I created an extension method clean up the Configure method, next I call a class to configure all my routes.

I don't know if it's the best solution, but it works fine... What do you think?
Thanks :)